# problem with ios ci/cd using xcode task in azure devops

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, azure-devops, devops

i want to create ci/cd for my ios app, i followed the guidelines on how to achieve it, generated the required certificate and provisioning profile and added them to the tasks:

Install an Apple certificate & Install an Apple provisioning profile.

and configured the xcode step as you can see in the attached snippet.

i tried lot's pf workarounds (adding extra arguments / changes the signing style to manual as you can see in the attachment.

and all other related workarounds but i keep getting the attached error.

**error: No profiles for 'com.poccadot.eggedLauncher.development' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.poccadot.eggedLauncher.development'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target '' from project '')**

what am i missing here?

Thanks a lot!

[image: error message]
[image: manuall sign-in]

[image: xcode task configuration #1]

[image: xcode task configuration #2]

Comment: from the line number 12, I saw that the code_sign method is automatic? And what do you mean `Apple certificate & Apple provisioning profile`? You have to install your own certificate, provisioning profile.

Comment: And your configure is wrong somehow, it shouldn't use iOS App Development certificate, in this case it should be Distribution certificate instead of Development, your bundle id in this case as well. What is bundle id for each build configuration?

Comment: Ad you can see in the screenshot i also tried to use the manual signin.. with the required variables inherited from my own certificate and provisioning profile..

Comment: how about the output when you choose manual signing? And do you know about different between development certificate and distribution certificate, different bundle id for each build configuration? I guess you wrongly used them.

Comment: for bundle ids, you can find it by select the project, then select `build setting` tab, then search `bundle identifier`, to see whether or not you're using different bundle id for each configuration

Comment: just to be on the same track .. i need to build dev & prod versions and i generated both certificates and provisioning profile (provisioning profile - *app store type* based on the *distribution type* certificate. then i'm using Install an Apple provisioning profile & Install an Apple provisioning profile predefined steps (that hold my generated p12 certificate from the downloaded cer) and my provision profile. after that i', kicking in the xcode steps and using manual signing (with the builtin variables see attached) sounds ok so far?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am getting the same error.